# Movement while screen/control is touched

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Having learned the basics of SpriteKit I am wondering how to implement this simple control mechanism: **Applying force to/moving a node *while* a view/node/control is held**.

I can only find methods applying force once.

Answer (score 0):

You know when touch began, and touch ended.

This means you need a flag.  let's call it `isBeingTouched`

On your touch down method, set `isBeingTouched = true`

On your touch up method, set `isBeingTouched = false`

Now the only thing we need is a continuous loop to constantly check this.

Best place for that is in update.

So in your update, you say

```
if isBeingTouched == true
{
  update you velocity or add force, whatever you need to do
}
```